# Cancelling background worker tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, backgroundworker

I have a background worker that performs a time consuming task, but I'm having trouble with the cancelling issue because I can manage to only flag cancellation and not actually terminate the process. In order to solve it, I tried to put some check points in the heavy function that I want to exit , but it seems not quite efficient. 
my code looks like this :

in some points in the heavy function I put those 2 lines :

```
if (general.backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
{ 
   return;
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //button invokes heavy function
{
    if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    heavyFunction(this);
    if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted_1(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        statusLabel.Text = "Status: cancelled";
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        statusLabel.Text = "ERROR!";
    }
    else
    {
        some code;
    }
}

private void cancelSDoutLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "invoking cancellation" ?  That is not a real term.

Comment: is `general` the `Form` object that you pass into the method `heavyFunction` ?

Comment: yes, indeed. sorry for not clarifying

Comment: Checking for `CancellationPending` and returning is helpful only if that code _can execute_. Which it can't until your `heavyFunction(this)` call returns. You need to pass cancellation context (e.g. the `BackgroundWorker` object all the way down to every point where you want to be able to interrupt the worker. See marked duplicates for some discussion, as well as many other `BackgroundWorker` questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Closed as a dupe but as summary: Yes, cancellation has to be cooperative.  Your code should not need it to be instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

Cancel can be a complicate function to implement and is often left as an afterthought.

If you want to cancel `heavyFunction` (which should be probably be `longRunningFunction` ;) it will have to become cancel aware. You said that you already put check points, which makes sense.

You can try to use more of cancellable method calls that accept a cancellation token. For example Task.Delay has two overloads:

```
Delay(TimeSpan)
```

and

```
Delay(TimeSpan, CancellationToken)
```

Another strategy is to split the method into smaller, shorter tasks.

Finally, the cancel operation doesn't have to instantaneous. 
You may end up with "Cancelling..." status that waits for a good moment to stop the job.